# Swift Call function from another ViewController

Tags: swift, func

I am trying to call a function in the 'attendees' viewController from the viewContoller named 'swipePage':

Attendees:

```
func showMatchedScreen(){
    matchedView.isHidden = false
}
```

swipePage:

```
attendees().showMatchedScreen()
```

However I keep getting the following error on the line above:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Hint: Delegate pattern/Notifications/creating an instance of VC/viewDidLoad,ViewWillAppear

Comment: The instance created with `attendees()` is not the instance in the storyboard. You need an IBOutlet or protocol / delegate or callback closure.